# Xerces-c and cross-platform string literals

Tags: c++, string, portability, xerces-c

I'm porting a code-base that uses Xerces-c for XML processing from Windows/VC++ to Linux/G++.

On Windows, Xerces-c uses `wchar_t` as the character type `XmlCh`.  This has allowed people to use `std::wstring` and string literals of `L""` syntax.

On Linux/G++, `wchar_t` is 32-bit and Xerces-c uses `unsigned short int` (16-bit) as the character type `XmlCh`.

I've started out along this track:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
using u16char_t = wchar_t;
using u16string_t = std::wstring;
#elif defined __linux
using u16char_t = char16_t;
using u16string_t = std::u16string;
#endif
```

Unfortunately, `char16_t` and `unsigned short int` are not equivalent and their pointers are not implicitly convertible.  So passing `u"Hello, world."` to Xerces functions still results in invalid conversion errors.

It's starting to look like I'm going to have to explicitly cast every string I pass to Xerces functions.  But before I do, I wanted to ask if anyone knows a saner way to programme cross-platform Xerces-c code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that no, no-one has a good idea on how to do this.  For anyone else who finds this question, this is what I came up with:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define U16S(x) L##x
#define U16XS(x) L##x

#define XS(x) x
#define US(x) x

#elif defined __linux

#define U16S(x) u##x
#define U16XS(x) reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short *>(u##x)

inline unsigned short *XS(char16_t* x) {
    return reinterpret_cast<unsigned short *>(x);
}
inline const unsigned short *XS(const char16_t* x) {
    return reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short *>(x);
}
inline char16_t* US(unsigned short *x) {
    return reinterpret_cast<char16_t *>(x);
}
inline const char16_t* US(const unsigned short *x) {
    return reinterpret_cast<const char16_t*>(x);
}

#include "char16_t_facets.hpp"
#endif

namespace SafeStrings {
#if defined _MSC_VER

    using u16char_t = wchar_t;
    using u16string_t = std::wstring;
    using u16sstream_t = std::wstringstream;
    using u16ostream_t = std::wostream;
    using u16istream_t = std::wistream;
    using u16ofstream_t = std::wofstream;
    using u16ifstream_t = std::wifstream;
    using filename_t = std::wstring;

#elif defined __linux

    using u16char_t = char16_t;
    using u16string_t = std::basic_string<char16_t>;
    using u16sstream_t = std::basic_stringstream<char16_t>;
    using u16ostream_t = std::basic_ostream<char16_t>;
    using u16istream_t = std::basic_istream<char16_t>;
    using u16ofstream_t = std::basic_ofstream<char16_t>;
    using u16ifstream_t = std::basic_ifstream<char16_t>;
    using filename_t = std::string;

#endif
```

`char16_t_facets.hpp` has definitions of the template specialisations `std::ctype<char16_t>`, `std::numpunct<char16_t>`, `std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>`.  It's necessary to add these to the global locale, along with `std::num_get<char16_t>` and `std::num_put<char16_t>` (but it's not necessary to provide specialisations for these).  The code for `codecvt` is the only bit that's difficult, and a reasonable template can be found in the GCC 5.0 libraries (if you use GCC 5, you don't need to provide the `codecvt` specialisation as it's already in the library).

Once you've done all of that, the `char16_t` streams will work correctly.

Then, every time you define a wide string, instead of `L"string"`, write `U16S("string")`.  Every time you pass a string to Xerces, write XS(string.c_str()) or U16XS("string") for literals.  Every time you get a string back from Xerces, convert it back as `u16string_t(US(call_xerces_function()))`.

Note that it is also possible to recompile Xerces-C with the character type set to char16_t.  This removes a lot of the effort required above.  **BUT** you won't be able to use any other library on the system that in turn depends on Xerces-C.  Linking to any such library will cause link errors (because changing the character type changes many of the Xerces function signatures).