# XMLCh to wchar_t and vice versa

Tags: c++, wchar-t, wstring

My config:

- Compiler: gnu gcc 4.8.2
- I compile with C++11
- platform/OS: Linux 64bit Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

I want to feed a method with wchar_t* and use it in many xecerces library methods that need XMLCh* but I don't know how to translate from one to another. It's easy if you use char* instead of wchar_t* but I need to use wide character. Under windows I could easily cast from one to another but it doesn't work in my linux machine. Somehow I have to manually translate wchar_t* to a XMLCh*

I link throught the library libxerces-c-3.1.so which uses XMLCh* exclusively. XMLCh can deal with wide character, but I don't know how to feed it to it, and also how to get a wchar_t* back from a XMLCh*

I developed this but it doesn't work (here I spit out a wstring which is easier to manage in cleaning up the memory than a pointer:

```
static inline std::wstring XMLCh2W(const XMLCh* tagname)
{
    std::wstring wstr;
    XMLSize_t len1 = XMLString::stringLen(tagname);
    XMLSize_t outLen = len1 * 4;
    XMLByte ut8[outLen+1];
    XMLSize_t charsEaten = 0;
    XMLTransService::Codes failReason; //Ok | UnsupportedEncoding | InternalFailure | SupportFilesNotFound
    XMLTranscoder* transcoder = XMLPlatformUtils::fgTransService->makeNewTranscoderFor("UTF-8", failReason,16*1024);

    unsigned int utf8Len = transcoder->transcodeTo(tagname,len1,ut8,outLen,charsEaten,XMLTranscoder::UnRep_Throw);// XMLTranscoder::UnRep_Throw UnRep_RepChar

    ut8[utf8Len] = 0;
    std::wstring wstr = std::wstring((wchar_t*)ut8);//I'm not sure this is actually ok to do
    return wstr;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782247/xerces-c-and-cross-platform-string-literals.  Not that you'll probably get any more answer here than I got there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that under GCC, because GCC defines `wchar_t` as a 32-bit, UTF-32/UCS-4-encoded (the difference is not important for practical purposes) string while Xerces-c defines XmlCh as a 16-bit UTF-16-encoded string.

The best I've found is to use the C++11 support for UTF-16 strings:

- `char16_t` and `XmlCh` are equivalent, though not implicitly convertible; you still need to cast between them.  But at least this is cheap, compared to transcoding.
- `std::basic_string<char16_t>` is the equivalent string type.
- Use literals of the form `u"str"` and `u's'`.

Unfortunately, VC++ doesn't support the C++11 UTF-16 literals, though `wchar_t` literals are UTF-16 encoded.  So I end up with something like this in a header:

```
#if defined _MSC_VER
#define U16S(x) L##x
typedef wchar_t my_u16_char_t;
typedef std::wstring my_u16_string_t;
typedef std::wstringstream my_u16_sstream_t;
inline XmlCh* XmlString(my_u16_char_t* s) { return s; }
inline XmlCh* XmlString(my_u16_string_t* s) { return s.c_str(); }
#elif defined __linux
#define U16S(x) u##x
typedef char16_t my_u16_char_t;
typedef std::basic_string<my_u16_char_t> my_u16_string_t;
typedef std::basic_stringstream<my_u16_char_t> my_u16_sstream_t;
inline XmlCh* XmlString(my_u16_char_t* s) { return reinterpret_cast<XmlCh*>(s); }
inline XmlCh* XmlString(my_u16_string_t* s) { return XmlString(s.c_str()); }
#endif
```

It is, IMO, rather a mess, but not one I can see getting sorted out until VC++ supports C++11 Unicode literals, allowing Xerces to be rewritten in terms of `char16_t` directly.

Comment: No problem.  Be aware, though, that the streams don't work without some extra magic, in particular an implementation of std::ctype<char16_t>, std::numpunct<char16_t> and std::codecvt<char, char16_t> (last one might be the wrong way around).  You then need to add those facets, and std::num_get<char16_t> and std::num_put<char16_t>, to the global locale.

Comment: You can use Xersesc define _NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED

Answer (score 3):

XMLCh is defined by wchar_t (on windows) or uint16_t (on Linux) and it is encoded with UTF-16.

Unfortunately, gcc 4.8.2 does not support std::wstring_convert to convert unicode string's encoding. But you can use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)'s locale::conv::utf_to_utf() to convert to/from XMLCh.

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

static inline std::wstring XMLCh2W(const XMLCh* xmlchstr)
{
    std::wstring wstr = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(xmlchstr);
    return wstr;
}

static inline std::basic_string<XMLCh> W2XMLCh(const std::wstring& wstr)
{
    std::basic_string<XMLCh> xmlstr = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<XMLCh>(wstr);
    return xmlstr;
}
```

If you want to use wchar_t* or XMLCh*, use c_str() method like below.

```
const wchar_t* wcharPointer = wstr.c_str();
const XMLCh* xmlchPointer = xmlstr.c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently dealt with this issue, and now that Visual Studio 2015 supports Unicode character and string literals, this is pretty easy to deal with in a cross-platform way. I use the following macro and `static_assert` to guarantee correctness:

```
#define CONST_XMLCH(s) reinterpret_cast<const ::XMLCh*>(u ## s)

static_assert(sizeof(::XMLCh) == sizeof(char16_t), 
    "XMLCh is not sized correctly for UTF-16.");
```

Example of usage:

```
const XMLCh* features = CONST_XMLCH("Core");
auto impl = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(features);
```

This works because Xerces defines an `XMLCh` to be 16 bits wide and to hold a UTF-16 string value, which perfectly matches up with definition given by the standard for a string literal prefixed by `u`. The compiler doesn't know this, and won't implicitly convert between `char16_t*` and `XMLCh*`, but you can get around this with a `reinterpret_cast`. And if for whatever reason you try to compile Xerces on a platform where the sizes don't match up, the `static_assert` will fail and draw attention to the problem.

Comment: Very interesting. Which c++ version would support that?

Comment: The UTF-16 literals and `char16_t` primitive type were added to the standard in C++11 (so pretty much any modern version of GCC or Clang should have them), but MSVC didn't support them until VS2015.