# Error: no matching function for call to ‘xercesc_3_2::DOMImplementation::createDocument(int, const wchar_t [19], int)’

Tags: c++, xml, xerces-c

I am not so experienced with c++ and xerces lib, so I want to ask how can I resolve this problem. I installed the xerces lib following the instructions [here](http://blog.ovidiuparvu.com/install-xerces-c-source-ubuntu-pc).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
//Mandatory for using any feature of Xerces.
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
//Use the Document Object Model (DOM) API
#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>
//Required for outputing a Xerces DOMDocument to a standard output stream (Also see: XMLFormatTarget)
#include <xercesc/framework/StdOutFormatTarget.hpp>
//Required for outputing a Xerces DOMDocument to the file system (Also see: XMLFormatTarget)
#include <xercesc/framework/LocalFileFormatTarget.hpp>

/*
compile with g++ xerces.cc -o xml -lxerces-c
*/

using namespace std;
XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_USE

void write_output_to_stream(DOMDocument* measurement_DOM_document);
void write_output_to_file(DOMDocument* measurement_DOM_document, const wchar_t* full_file_path);

int main() {
     XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();

     /* Pointer to our DOM implementation */
     DOMImplementation* p_dom_implementation = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(XMLString::transcode("core"));
     /*  */
     DOMDocument* p_dom_document = p_dom_implementation->createDocument(0, L"dummy_measurements", 0);

     DOMElement* p_root_element = p_dom_document->getDocumentElement();

     XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
     return 0;
}
```

This is not the finished code yet, I just tried to compile.
Compiler output:

```
xerces.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
xerces.cc:29:100: error: no matching function for call to ‘xercesc_3_2::DOMImplementation::createDocument(int, const wchar_t [19], int)’
      DOMDocument* p_dom_document = p_dom_implementation->createDocument(0, L"dummy_measurements", 0);
                                                                                                    ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp:41:0,
                 from xerces.cc:7:
/usr/local/include/xercesc/dom/DOMImplementation.hpp:174:26: note: candidate: virtual xercesc_3_2::DOMDocument* xercesc_3_2::DOMImplementation::createDocument(const XMLCh*, const XMLCh*, xercesc_3_2::DOMDocumentType*, xercesc_3_2::MemoryManager*)
     virtual DOMDocument *createDocument(const XMLCh *namespaceURI,
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/xercesc/dom/DOMImplementation.hpp:174:26: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const wchar_t [19]’ to ‘const XMLCh* {aka const char16_t*}’
/usr/local/include/xercesc/dom/DOMImplementation.hpp:214:26: note: candidate: virtual xercesc_3_2::DOMDocument* xercesc_3_2::DOMImplementation::createDocument(xercesc_3_2::MemoryManager*)
     virtual DOMDocument *createDocument(MemoryManager* const manager = XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager) = 0;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/xercesc/dom/DOMImplementation.hpp:214:26: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
```

Comment: You need to convert `const wchar *` to `const XMLCh *`. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839725/xmlch-to-wchar-t-and-vice-versa can help.

Comment: You're battling the difference between wchar_t and char16_t.  Use u"..." instead of L"..." to keep the compiler happy about it.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: Thank you Hans Passant, It's worked.

Comment: I used this, if doesnt fix, XMLString::transcode("") instead L""